# Есть ли аналоги chat-api под whatsapp api?

Tags: php, битрикс, whatsapp

Необходимо реализовать плагин под битрикс, с возможностью отправки и принятия сообщений через сайт. Первая идея была - апи, нашел старый chat-api на гите, провозился весь день, не хочет работать. Как я понял, он регистрирует новый аккаунт на номер телефона, что вообще мне не нужно, так как необходимо использовать готовый аккаунт.

Следующая проблема состоит в том, что он тупо не логинится, не воспринимает пароль через регистрацию или зависает. Просмотрел аналоги, нашел нечто подобное https://chat-api.com .

Там вообще аутентификация реализуется через QR код, и я не понимаю, как они ловят пароли таким образом. Кто сможет посоветовать годный аналог устаревшего (как я понял) chat-api? И возможно ли в принципе реализовать описанный проект?

Comment: Удачи с вацапом)) эта хрень никак не интегрируется. Есть несколько сервисов, которые являются как бы вацап веб с возможностью вести переписку в CRM или реализовать свою логику. Не всегда это стабильно, а также из-за сложности реализации стоимость сервисов от 2к в месяц за номер

Comment: так что можешь не тратить время. Даже если что-то получится (аналог вацап веб на вебсокете), через некоторое непродолжительное время придется фиксить баги, т.к. вацап постоянно дорабатывает алгоритмы зациты от интеграций))

Answer (score 1):

chat-api от mgp 25 устарел потому что изменилась система безопасности в whatasapp. chat-api.com используют веб апи, а точнее связку docker + python + selenium. Т.е. это эмуляция запущенного веб ватсап на сервере где вы можете отправлять и принимать сообщения, т.е. все через АПИ обращения идет через JSON.

Comment: А не будет у вас примеров исходников подобных приложений? Проект уже реализовал через закрытый апи, просто интересно построить подобную систему для себя.